# ASP.NET Core. Защита jwt токенов

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

Я использую в своем проекте jwt токены. Код для создания `ClaimsIdentity`:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetClaimsIdentityAsync(User user)
{
    var roles = await _roleService.GetUserRolesAsync(user);

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Username),
    };
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role.Name));
    }
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity =
        new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Token", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
    return claimsIdentity;
}
```

Код для создания токена:

```
public async Task<string> GetJwtToken(User user)
{
    var identity = await _sinInService.GetClaimsIdentityAsync(user);

    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: AuthOptions.ISSUER,
        audience: AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
        notBefore: now,
        claims: identity.Claims,
        expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AuthOptions.LIFETIME)),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
}
```

Код в классе `Startup`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            ValidateLifetime = true,

            IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
    });
```

Код был взят из этой статьи: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php

Получив строку токена можно авторизоваться с любого браузера или устройства.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы токеном мог воспользоваться только тот, кому он был предназначен. 
Думаю сделать это таким образом: на серверной стороне генерируется уникальный ключ. Этот ключ потом отправляется вместе с jwt токеном в каждом запросе, что позволяет определить какое устройство получает доступ. Но этот ключ тоже могут украсть, как и сам токен :(

Также необходимо сделать так, чтобы если параметры пользователя изменились, ранее выданные токены стали невалидными. Ничего лучше, чем черный список токенов в бд я для этого не придумал. Должны же быть какие-то стандартные методы для сброса токенов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Получив строку токена, можно авторизоваться с любого браузера или устройства.

Да, эта проблема, которую токены аутентификации не решают. Поэтому важно реализовать следующие возможности:

1. Использовать HTTPS вместо HTTP, это защитит от перехвата токенов.
2. При сохранении токенов, использовать средства ОС, которые прячут их от других программ/пользователей. Например, в Андроид-приложениях задействуйте [Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) с флагом [MODE_PRIVATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE).
3. Делайте время жизни токена небольшим, например, 20 или 30 минут. Плюсом токена, относительно логина и пароля является время жизни: даже если его удалось перехватить, обычно это случается слишком поздно.

> Ничего лучше, чем черный список токенов в бд я для этого не придумал. Должны же быть какие-то стандартные методы для сброса токенов.

Для того, чтобы токены можно было отключать, например, реализовывать логаут, их действительно придётся хранить. Мы для этого используем не БД, а кэш Redis, где указываем время хранения. И работает быстрее, и старые записи чистить не надо.

Порядок действий:

1. При создании токена генерируете уникальный идентификатор токена ["jti" (JWT ID)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7). Создаёте токен доступа (access token).
2. В Redis (ну или в БД) заносите access_token с ключом, основанном на "jti", указав время жизни токена доступа (30 минут).
3. При аутентификации проверяете подпись JWT и время жизни, хранящееся в самом JWT. Если всё нормально, извлекаете значение "jti" и проверяете, есть ли такой ключ в Redis. Если есть, всё нормально, если нет, значит, был логаут, или пользователя выкинул администратор. В любом случае считаем, что пользователь аутентификацию не прошёл.

Такое решение позволяет реализовать логаут и бан и является достаточно безопасным.

Из-за короткого времени жизни токена доступа, необходимо реализовать перелогин через токен обновления. Этот токен тоже нужно хранить в Redis, только время жизни задавать больше (вполне нормальным считается даже месяц, но вы смотрите, что подходит к вашей предметной области).

При логауте/бане токен обновления также нужно удалять, как и токен доступа.

Дальше идут детали, которые вам придётся учитывать. Если нужен бан, значит, администратору каким-то образом нужно уметь узнавать "jti" по идентификатору пользователя. Можно например "jti" делать равным "sub" (то есть идентификатору пользователя). В этом случае пользователь не сможет одновременно работать с разных устройств, потому что у него может быть только один токен доступа. Если нужно, чтобы мог работать, можно например "jti" формировать в виде `$"{sub}:{random}"`. Тут возможны разные решения в зависимости от предметной области, но в целом ничего сложного нет.

Answer (score 0):

Сервер знает о клиенте только то, что клиент прислал ему в http-запросе.

По сути, это только:

- Client IP, который может меняться.
- UserAgent, который неуникален.

Так что ответ - провалидировать привязку токена к девайсу не получится.